# Paperclip::NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError when file is not a valid attachment content type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attachment, paperclip

I have systematically an error when I'm trying to upload a file that is not in `["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/pjpeg", "image/x-png"]`

When I try to upload a file like a 'wav' I have this message

`* Photo /var/folders/nT/nTr21TWfFRO7r3cyG-h-7++++TM/-Tmp-/Clip audio 01,39154,0.wav is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
* Photo /var/folders/nT/nTr21TWfFRO7r3cyG-h-7++++TM/-Tmp-/Clip audio 01,39154,0.wav is not recognized by the 'identify' command.
* Photo content type Accepted files include: jpg, gif, png`

So it detects that the file is not an image and display my message `"Accepted files include: jpg, gif, png"` but I have this extra message included before mine Photo is not recognized by the 'identify' command...
Upload works fine for pictures

My code is:

**Controller:**

```
def upload  
  @picture= Picture.new(params[:picture])  
    if !@picture.valid?  
        render  :form  
    end  
end
```

**View form:**

```
<%= error_messages_for :picture, :header_message => nil, :message => nil %>  
<% form_for :picture, @picture, :name => "uploadPic", :url => { :action => 'upload_data'}, :html => {:name => 'uploadForm', :multipart => true } do |form| %>  
    <%= form.file_field :photo %>  
    <%= submit_tag 'Save'%>  
<% end %>
```

**Picture model:**

```
 class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base    
    require 'paperclip'  
    has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }  

    validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 2.megabytes , :message => "must be less than 2 megabytes"  
    validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/gif", "image/png", "image/pjpeg", "image/x-png"], :message => "Accepted files include: jpg, gif, png"   

 end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

solved it with :whiny => false
    has_attached_file :photo, :whiny => false, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }

Comment: when using your fix its not creating :medium and :thumb images, just :original

Answer (score 3):

:whiny => false was not enough to solve the problem with the latest version of paperclip (2.3.6). I ended up doing this in a rails initializer:

```
module Paperclip
  class Attachment
    alias original_assign assign
    def assign(*args)
      original_assign(*args)
    rescue NotIdentifiedByImageMagickError => e
    end
  end
end
```

It seems okay to swallow that exception because validation errors get added anyway at least if you use :whiny => true.